# Why does my recursive strlen function return value 4 times bigger?

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings

I'm trying to implement a `strlen` function in C with recursion and for some reason it's returning a 4 times bigger value than expected.

```
int *strlen(char *s)
{
   if(*s == '\0')
       return 0;
   else
       return 1 + strlen(s+1);
}
```

Interestingly, when I change the type return of the function to "char", I get the desired result. I don't understand why, it should return an int anyways. I copied this code from a book, it should be right.

Comment: Why do you return a pointer from your function?

Comment: that's the issue: pointer arithmetic with 32 bit int = 4 times the expected result!

Comment: _I copied this code from a book, it should be right_ if the prototype is `int *` then the book is wrong

Comment: In the future, you can debug issues like this must faster by enabling compiler warnings. This is what GCC has to say about your code with warnings enable (`-Wall -Wextra`): https://godbolt.org/z/r8MKrYcMP

Comment: OT: `else` is unnecessary. If `if()` is true, `return` makes `else` superfluous. Less code is clearer code, imho...

Comment: OT: It's a bad idea to use the name of a well known standard library function in your own code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre maybe they want something weird like in second part of my answer

Comment: I know it's just an exercise, but such a function isn't efficient at all. Its complexity is _quadratic_ It will loop 500000 times to compute the size of a 1000-char string (or will crash before with "infinite recursion" maybe)

Answer (score 7):

Your function returns a pointer. On your system, an `int` is 4 bytes. Pointer arithmetic means that adding 1 to an int pointer increases its value by 4. When you change the return value to `char *` it "works" because `char` is 1 byte, so pointer arithmetic means that adding 1 to a char pointer increments its value by 1.

Your function does not need to return a *pointer* at all.

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
  if (*s == '\0')
      return 0;
  else
      return 1 + strlen(s+1);
}
```

*It'd be even more appropriate to have it return `size_t` than `int`.*

Answer (score 1):

1. `strlen` should return `size_t` not `int`.
2. You return a pointer instead of an integer.

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    return *str ? 1 + mystrlen(str + 1) : 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%zu\n", mystrlen("Hello"));
}
```

> I copied this code from a book, it should be right

If they want you to return pointer to the integer then maybe they want something weird like this:

```
int *mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    static int first = 1;
    static int size = 0;
    if(first) {size = 0; first = 0;}

    if(*str)
    {
        size++;
        mystrlen(str + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        first = 1;
    }
    return &size;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", *mystrlen("Hello"));
    printf("%d\n", *mystrlen(" World"));
}
```

Comment: UV for renaming the function.